# limit container connection on specific ip address

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, docker

I just run a container on `8000:8000` my server `192.168.1.10` so if I run curl 192.168.1.10:8000 from another server (like 192.168.1.50) it will return hello-world from my API.

I want to limit the connection to my API so just one or two specific IP can connect to 8000 of server `192.168.1.10`. after run `systemctl restart docker.service` iptables create some rules automatically as shown in attachment bellow.
it has no affect on 192.168.1.50 or any other IP address on my network it always shows `hello-world` if i curl it from anywhere.
how can I limit this to just one / two IP address (like 192.168.1.50).

[image: attachment_image]

Comment: Please  use copy-paste and avoid posting screenshots of text when posting console output / settings. Format that text  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions. And that will allow people willing to answer your question to also copy-and-paste your commands/settings/error messages into their answer.

Comment: That is explained in the manual https://docs.docker.com/network/packet-filtering-firewalls/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host